# Dashboard with bootstrap, why left hand menu doesn't work min-height: 100%, but it does with px?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I want to create a dashboard from scratch for learning purposes using Bootstrap 3.3.7. I have problem with the left hand menu. I want it to occupy the whole area it gets (col-lg-1 column and 100% height). My problem is that the `min-height:100%` with `height: auto` doesn't work, but `min-height:xxx px` works well.

I saw other posts here saying that `min-height:100%` should work.

What I'm doing wrong?

Here is the [plunker](https://embed.plnkr.co/VQPZ8t/).

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <link data-require="bootstrap@3.3.7" data-semver="3.3.7" rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <script data-require="bootstrap@3.3.7" data-semver="3.3.7" src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script src="script.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <main style="margin-top: 0px; padding-top: 0px; padding-bottom: 0px;">
        <div class="container-fluid padding-left-zero padding-right-zero">
            <div class="container-fluid padding-left-zero padding-right-zero">
                <div style="margin-bottom: -20px;">
                    <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">

                        <div class=" container-fluid row">
                            <div class="pull-left">
                                <a class="navbar-brand" href="/">Dashboard</a>
                            </div>
                            <div style="height: 50px; padding: 15px;" class="pull-right">
                                <select>
                                    <option value="module">value</option>
                                </select>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </nav>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row container-fluid padding-left-zero padding-right-zero">
                <!-- code of lenfthandmenu -->
                <!-- <div class="col-lg-1 pull-left navbar-inverse fill">
                    <div ui-view="leftHandMenu"></div>
                </div>-->
                <div class="col-lg-1 pull-left navbar-inverse fill2">
                    <div ui-view="leftHandMenu"></div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-11 pull-right">
                    <div ui-view="mainContent"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div>
                <div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-bottom">Navbar bottom</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </main>
</body>

</html>
```

Css:

```
/* Styles go here */

body {
    padding-top: 50px;
}
.padding-left-zero {
    padding-left: 0px;
}

.padding-right-zero {
    padding-right: 0px;
}

li {
    list-style: none;
}

.silver-text {
    color: silver;
}

.min-width-100-percent {
    min-width: 100%;
}

.fill {
    min-height: 100%;
    height: auto;
}

.fill2 {
    min-height: 300px;
    height: auto;
}
```

Comment: Percentage height depends on parent. If you parent is just block element - it's height depends on it's content - snake eating it's tail... You may try to use `vh` height (as 100vh = 100% window height) but probably there are other page elements (you didn't provide any code so noone will really give you working solution) so it won't work as you wish. Simplest solution would be to use JS to set height according to other elements.

Comment: @PrzemysławMelnarowicz: thanks for your answer! I thought it is enough to provide a plunker link. I updated my question.

Comment: Sorry about that, must missed Plunker link somehow... it was late. You want this left menu to be relative (scrollable with page content) or fixed (always on place, scrolled independently)?

Comment: It will be filled up by menu, so there is a change it should be scrollable independently..

Comment: Something like that? http://codepen.io/themeler/pen/JEBmOZ

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apply absolute position property and height as 100% like below.

```
.fill2 {
   position:absolute;
   height: 100%;
}
```

[**DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/5xLb81mk/)